# Unable to send JSON string from HTML form to Web API controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have this Web API in C#. When I submit the form, it doesn't reach this action method.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] string jsonString)
{

}
```

When I submit the form, this is the output for `stringifyObj` in the console.log and I got a 415 error code.

```
{"application_name":"1225848d-5941-4fac-bdff-7799b53d6fd0test1","asset_type":"1225848d-5941-4fac-bdff-7799b53d6fd1test2"}
```

and this is my front-end code.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://localhost:7273/WeatherForecast',
    type: 'POST',
    data: stringifyObj,
    dataType: 'application/json',
    success: function (response) {
        debugger
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        debugger
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText)
    }
});
```

When I remove the `[FromBody]` at the Web API action method, the error becomes:

```
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-1841751068f6545f081cd59195b65b0d-f07b55a84e3d8b29-00","errors":{"jsonString":["The jsonString field is required."]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `Post` action to expect to receive the request body of `Model` (object) type instead of `string` type.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] Model model)
{

}
```

```cs
public class Model
{
    [JsonProperty("application_name")]
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("asset_type")]
    public Guid AssetType { get; set; }
}
```

While in Ajax:

1. Add `contentType: "application/json"`.
2. For `dataType`, should be "json" instead of "application/json".

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://localhost:7273/WeatherForecast',
        type: 'POST',
        data: stringifyObj,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            debugger
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            debugger
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText)
        }
    });
```

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have a concrete model. My database design is Entity-Attribute-Value EAV approach

Comment: Hmmm, so your API action should expect any kind of object as what I understand?

Comment: Yes, it's dynamic

Comment: I see, how about using the `dynamic` type? `[FromBody] dynamic model`

Comment: When I tried that, the error message becomes `{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"00-08310a0a1de1d0f9172ff2c7b80c360e-4205eb0894a36519-00"}`

Comment: Hmmm, but on my local side able to work. [Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gC0ez.png)